# how to have a new line from within brackets

Tags: cursor-motions

I normally write my functions this way

```
public void test() {}
```

to continue, I need to insert a new line from within the brackets, so the final output is this:

```
public void test(){
    // cursor is here now
}
```

To do so in vim, I follow these steps: (the pipe is where the cursor at)

```
public void test() {}
```

I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go to normal mode, then <kbd>j</kbd> so now my cursor is here:

```
public void test() {|}
```

I press <kbd>i</kbd> to go to insert mode and then <kbd>enter</kbd> twice so now I have this:

```
public void test() {

|}
```

then I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go to normal mode and then <kbd>k</kbd> to go up a line, and then <kbd>i</kbd> to go to insert mode and then <kbd>tab</kbd> to get to the desired outcome.

Is there a better way?

**Note:** I really don't wanna use plugins, I hope native vim helps me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim mapping to auto-indent when entering inside braces, brackets etc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26718/vim-mapping-to-auto-indent-when-entering-inside-braces-brackets-etc)

Answer (score 2):

Turn on [:h 'autoindent'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27autoindent%27) and [:h 'smartindent'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27smartindent%27) , assume current typing is:

```
public void test(){
```

input <kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>:

```
public void test(){
}
```

input <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>:

```
public void test(){
    |
}
```

If you prefer [:h i_CTRL-O](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O) , replace <kbd>esc</kbd> with <kbd>ctrl-o</kbd>.

FYI, another way to reindent current line in `insert mode` is [:h i_CTRL-F](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#i_CTRL-F) .

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is here from the future, you could also add on to @dedowsdi's answer by making a keybinding that does the operation for you.

In your `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap bb {<Enter>}<Esc><S-o>
```

Reload `vim` and while in `insert mode` hit `bb`.

Comment: The `<S-o>` can be written as just `O`, and you might want to use inoremap.

Comment: Great additions, thank you, D. Ben Knoble.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the line below in your `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap { {<Esc>o<Esc>o}<Esc>ki<tab>
```

Then when you will type `{` it will automatically put your cursor in the position you want and close the `}`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might be able to use `<C-o>k` instead of `<Esc>ki`