# Vim mapping to auto-indent when entering inside braces, brackets etc

Tags: key-bindings, indent

Which vim mapping/ plugin will help me in auto-indenting when entering inside braces, brackets or any similar characters. For example:

Input `{press enter}`

Output

```
{
       
    cursor here

}
```

I want this behaviour for brackets, parentheses etc also.

Comment: This usually works with an indent plugin/expression for your filetype (see :help indent.txt`); which filetype specifically do you want this for? There may already be a setting in the existing indent plugin to change the behaviour of how this works.

Answer (score 1):

I guess all bracketing plugins have this behaviour for brackets at least. This is the case of lh-brackets for instance.

And it's quite easy to extend to anything else. The important part is CR+ESC+O, O is what will ensure a correct indent. See this related answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708395/how-to-move-opening-curly-braces-to-a-new-line-in-vim

This will look like to something like the following (untested)

```
inoremap <expr> <cr> 
   \ : getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=~'{}\|()\|\[\]\|<>' ? "<cr><esc>O"
   \ :                                                           "<cr>"
```

Note: you'll also have to activate auto indent in your sessions.